# Orientation of Vector Space Arising From a Vector

Tags: tensors, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I'm self-studying Gullemin's "Differential Forms."  It's very interesting but, for me at least, challenging not to have the benefits of a professor or lectures.  I'm having trouble understanding the material in Section 1.9, which concerns orientations of vector spaces.  In particular, I have a question about the last part of problem 1.9.vi:

"**Exercise 1.9.vi.**  Let $V$ be an oriented $n$-dimensional vector space and $W$ an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.  Show that if $v$ and $v'$ are in $V \backslash W$ then $v' = \lambda v + \omega$ where $\omega$ is in $W$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.  Show that $v$ and $v'$ give rise to the same orientation of $W$ if and only if $\lambda$ is positive."

I've solved the first part (i.e., finding $\lambda$ and $\omega$ such that $v' = \lambda v + \omega$).  I don't understand the last sentence.  I've re-read Section 1.9 several times, and I'm not clear how vectors $v$ and $v'$ give rise to an orientation of $W$.  Can someone please explain or point me to an online resource that will clarify this?  Note that I'm not looking for a solution (although feel free to provide hints), just enough information so I understand the problem.

For context, you can find an early draft of this book at https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.952/2018SP/files/18.952_book.pdf.  See page 43 of the PDF.

Many thanks for your assistance!

Best,
Doug

Comment: An orientation of a vector space is, essentially, an equivalence class on bases, where two bases are in the same class if their vectors are oriented internally in the same way. Like, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, two bases would share the same orientation if they defined the same Right Hand Rule. You can convince yourself that this relationship is equivalent to the change of basis having positive jacobian determinant.

Answer (score 1):

An orientation is the choice of an $n$ alternated form $\omega$, the orientation induced by $v$ on $W$ is the $n-1$ form $\omega_v(w_1,..,w_{n-1})=\omega(v,w_1,..,w_{n-1})$, suppose that $v'=\lambda v+w, \lambda>0$, $\omega_{v'}(w_1,..,w_{n-1})=\omega(\lambda v+w,w_1,..,w_{n-1})=\lambda\omega(v,w_1,..,w_{n-1})=\lambda \omega_v(w_1,..,w_{n-1})$.

We deduce that $\omega_{v'}=\lambda\omega_v$ which is equivalent to saying that $\omega_v$ and $\omega_{v'}$ define the same orientation if and only if $\lambda>0$.

Comment: +1 this is a much cleaner approach than what I wrote

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

My guess of what they mean is that since $v\in V\setminus W$, it is a non-zero vector. Now, we can choose an ordered basis $\beta:= \{w_1, \dots, w_{n-1}\}$ of $W$, and then we can extend it to an ordered basis $B_v:= \{v, w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ a basis of $V$. The basis $B_v$ could be either positively oriented or it could be negatively oriented (with respect to the given orientation on $V$). We shall now prescribe an orientation on $W$ by saying (the equivalence class containing) $\beta$ is positively-oriented if and only if $B_v$ is a positively oriented basis.

Similarly, using $v'$, we get another basis $B_{v'}$, which then induces an orientation on $W$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!